# Is it possible to make dual Asus touch screen monitors work as two different workplaces on one computer

Tags: multiple-monitors, touchscreen

Is it possible to make dual Asus touchscreen monitors work on one computer so that they work as two different workplaces?

I've already set up touchscreen monitors and calibrated them. Already tried to use for example "Paint" on both of the screens at the same time, but it only lets me use Paint on one monitor at the time, not two at the same time.

Is there any way to make it possible? If you need any clarification, let me know.